# if statement and for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

This is the piece i'm trying to run. It has worked and then it started messing up. Basically it is meant to iterate through a for loop and if inptype != sale then it is meant to skip the iteration of the loop and continue with the next one. However, when the value does not the statement it should skip to the else statement and continue, but it doesn't and it follows the procedure for inptype != sale even when the value does equal sale.

Here is my code

```
for row in reader:
    inpname = str(row[15])
    inptype = str(row[19])
    print(inptype)
    print (inpname)
    if not row: # if row is blank
        print("not row")
        continue# continue loop on next iteration of for loop
    elif "CUSTOMER DISCOUNT" in inpname:
        print("customer dis")
        continue
    elif inptype != "Sale" or "sale" or "SALE":
        continue
    else:
```

Comment: It is impossible to say anything with messed up intendations - you need to fix that, otherwise no one can help. Also, it's unlikely that this thing ran, there's no intended block after the last ```else:```

Comment: Are inpname and inptype supposed to be single characters? The way you are indexing row is only going to return a single letter. Perhaps research python string slicing?

Comment: Also, just to let you know the conditional statement: `inptype != "Sale" or "sale" or "SALE"` will always be `True`. You may wanted to write: `inptype != "Sale" and inptype != "sale" and inptype != "SALE"`

Comment: @rammelmueller the code runs perfectly fine it's just as soon as i added the elif statement with the multiple conditions. I obviously didn't format it correctly, but the rest of the code has been working fine for well over a month. I know the indentation is completely off, in my IDLE it runs correctly it's just when I pasted it into StackOverflow it got messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

`inpname = str(row[15])` takes the content of a field with index 16 of an array-like object and converts the result into a string. As this clearly does not fail - you'd see an exception and report a completely different error here - we can conclude: `row` is not `None`.

Now look at `if not row:`: As `row` is not `None` the `continue` will not be executed.

Second:

In `elif inptype != "Sale" or "sale" or "SALE":` the `or` is a boolean operation. You've three individual terms here: `inptype != "Sale"`, `"sale"`, `"SALE"`. The last two terms always evaluate to `True` as both strings are not empty. So effectively you're evaluating `(inptype != "Sale") or True or True` here (which is likely not what you intended as this always evaluates to `True`). So before continuing with any more analysis of your code rephrase this line into:

`elif (inptype != "Sale") or (inptype != "sale") or (inptype != "SALE"):`

Comment: Thankyou for your help. It works now much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! And feel free to accept this answer!